# How can I customize a SQL Server Data-tier Application before export?

Tags: sql-server, azure, dacpac

I understand a Data-tier Application (DACPAC) is the schema of a database tidied away into a series of XML files combined into a zip/DACPAC file and this allows for better management and upgrades through SQL Server, so far, so good.

I want to create a DACPAC from my application database, however the database contains tables and other objects only used for dev/testing purposes (e.g. Diagrams), as well as User objects (which are machine-specific anyway). There is also the matter of a few tables that contain minimum data needed to run the application, such as my `Settings` and `Users` table.

However the DACPAC wizard does not let me exclude tables or objects from the process, nor does it let me include "minimum data" either - making it patently useless to me as a means of deploying application instances.

How can I exclude tables and objects from a DACPAC, and how can I include data rows?

(FWIW, I'm looking to deploy to Azure SQL, which does not work well with SSIS, which is how I normally deploy data)